# Setting variables from a JavaScript animation object prototype

Tags: javascript, canvas, sprite

I'm trying to follow an example from a book on doing animation with the JS Canvas.

One of the examples creates a sprite from a prototype with the following call:

```
sprite = new Sprite('runner',
                        new SpriteSheetPainter(runnerCells),
                        [ runInPlace, moveLeftToRight ]);
```

"runnerCells" is a reference to the JS array that determines the position of each cell of the animation on the spritesheet.  What I don't get it how I can access the "sprite" variable in a way that allows me to change "runnerCells" to a different array to create a different animation.  Any suggestions?

You can see the full example in action here:
http://corehtml5canvas.com/code-live/ch06/example-6.9/example.html

With the relevant JS library located here:
http://corehtml5canvas.com/code-live/ch06/example-6.9/example.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be wrong but it doesn't look like Sprite exposes it's SpriteSheetPainter instance. You could try not to pass it anonymously but create a variable so you can reference it and pass that variable

```
var ssp = new SpriteSheetPainter(runnerCells)
var sprite = new Sprite('runner',
                        ssp,
                        [ runInPlace, moveLeftToRight ]);
console.log(ssp.cells);
```